# Regex problem for extract words from the larger list which meet certain conditions using python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-re

I am trying to extract words from the list that meet certain conditions. It  read each line and if the line ends with ")" and in that line it extract words starting from "." and " " space and end to "(" and replace with "function_call".
I am using regex to extract specific words, It works totally fine with smaller dataset(1 millions line of code). But when I use larger dataset (100 millions lines of code). regex give Memoryerror.

The script and code data example.

```
import re
data = ["int k = b.k(parcel)",
"int k = kon(parcel)",
"int a", 
"int bds",
"obtain.appendFrom(parcel, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
"obtain desFrom(package, dataPosition2, readInt2)",
"int abd(callme)",
"int.dbd(callyou)",
"int throw new UnsupportedOperationException(you)",
"int throw new.UnsupportedOperationException(me)"]

c_data = [
    re.sub(r"(\w+)\s*\(", "function_call(", i)
    for i in data
]
```

I am trying to use a for loop to extract and replace.

```
g = []
for i in data:
    if " " or "." in i and i.endswith(")"):
          g = i.replace(f"{i}","function_call")
          clean_data.append(g)
```

But I feels, something is wrong with the for loop code and it is not executing as expected.

Output should be like:

```
int k = b.function_call(parcel)
int k = function_call(parcel)
int a 
int bds
obtain.function_call(parcel, dataPosition2, readInt2)
obtain function_call(package, dataPosition2, readInt2)
int function_call(callme)
int.function_call(callyou)
int throw new function_call(you)
int throw new.function_call(me)
```

Comment: Try to read data in chunks, then process it (save to disk) and read the next chunk. Alternatively, read the file one line at a time with `readline` and process each line individually and save the result to disk each time, then you keep the memory usage down.

Comment: What is the code doing that is not expected?  If you use a debugger, what is the *first* unexpected thing that it does?